# Setup bamboo on google cloud engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup bamboo on Google Cloud engine, I could not find any way to change the default startup url/ip, it boots on localhost:8085 for setup, I used links (headless/text browser) to set it up, after that I went to bamboo home directory to change the url, after I changed it in "Bamboo Home/xml-data/configuration/administration.xml" and restarted bamboo, I am unable to access it from outside GCE.

For info I assigned a fixed IP to the VM created on Google Cloud engine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you created the appropriate firewall rules in GCE network to allow external traffic? You can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewall_rules) for more information on GCE firewall rules.

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue. If not, you can provide further information as previously requested to further troubleshooting.

Comment: Nothing to do with GCE as everything is set already. No I couldn't,  I went with another solution they just added to bitbuckey Pipelines,  with custom Docker image that I pushed to my Docker hub.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [3rd party services](https://deploy4me.com/en/install/bamboo.html) that will automate the deployment.

As a side note, GCE external IP addresses are not directly attached to the server. i.e. “ifconfig” will only return an [internal IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872549/bind-external-ip-google-cloud-engine), the mapping between the external IP and the internal one is done by [Google network layer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking). It is always advisable to verify that services are bound to listen to any interface.

Comment: Link is blocked by ublock-badware filter.